# How can I filter to a Joined Item column in a Data View?

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2013, dataview

When I generate a filter using the Filter dialog, SPD generates the following row filter...

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Benefits/Rows/Row[normalize-space(@Benefit_x0020_Type) = $pBenefit and normalize-space(@Level) = $pLevel]"/>
```

The filter for @Benefit_x0020_Type works just fine (this is just a regular, non-linked, item), but the filter for @Level does not work. @Level is a Joined Item, declared as follows...

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="../../../Projects/Rows/Row[@ID=current()/@Project_x003a_ID]/@Level" />
```

How can I make the filter work for the Joined Item?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to edit the $Rows node-set to include the joined fields before it is ever rendered by SharePoint...

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Benefits/Rows/Row"/>

<xsl:variable name="myRowsFractured">
  <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
    <xsl:variable name="projectID" select="@Project_x003a_ID"/>
    <xsl:variable name="level" select="/dsQueryResponse/Projects/Rows/Row[@ID=$projectID]/@Level"/>
    <xsl:if test="$level = $pLevel">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="Level">
          <xsl:value-of select="$level"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Title">
          <xsl:value-of select="/dsQueryResponse/Projects/Rows/Row[@ID=$projectID]/@Title"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="myRows" select="msxsl:node-set($myRowsFractured)/*"/>
```

($pLevel is acquired from the Query string)

I then replace any subsequent reference of $Rows to $myRows. This technique has the advantage of any calculation (such as dvt_RowCount) being valid.